# C# How to calculate all 3 letter combinations with a certain value

Tags: c#, combinations

I have 11 letters and they have values. The first have the same value as their numbering 1 to 10, but the eleventh has a value of 20. The question is how can I print out all 3 letter combinations with a total value of 23. Can you please help me I don’t even know where to start?

Comment: [Start by solving a simpler problem](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is a brute-force solution, where you compare every possible combination of three-letter values and store those that equal 23.

First, a simple class to represent a `Letter`, that has a `Text` property and a `Value` property:

```
public class Letter
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public char Text { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Text} ({Value})";
    }
}
```

Then, we can populate a list of these from `A-K`, where each letter has it's corresponding "index + 1" value except the last, which is 20:

```
var letters = Enumerable.Range(65, 10)
    .Select(i => new Letter {Value = i - 64, Text = (char)i })
    .ToList();

letters.Add(new Letter {Value = 20, Text = 'K'});
```

Then we can create a `List<List<Letter>>` object to hold the combinations that add up to `23`:

```
var combos = new List<List<Letter>>();
```

And the brute-force solution is to simply use 3 loops to add a `List<Letter>` of the sum of each number with every combination of two numbers after it:

```
for (int first = 0; first < letters.Count; first++)
{
    for (int second = first + 1; second < letters.Count; second++)
    {
        for (int third = second + 1; third < letters.Count; third++)
        {
            combos.Add(new List<Letter>
            {letters[first], letters[second], letters[third]});
        }
    }
}
```

When this is done, we can filter and display the results of only those whose sum is 23:

```
// Output the combinations
Console.WriteLine("Here are the combinations that equal 23:\r\n");

foreach (var combo in combos.Where(c => c.Sum(l => l.Value) == 23))
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" +\t", combo) +
                      $"\t= {combo.Sum(l => l.Value)}");
}
```

**Output**

[image: image of console output]

Answer (score 0):

Let's first put your letters into a `Dictionary<string, int>` where `Key` is the letter, and `Value` is the value associated with each key.

```
var values = new Dictionary<string, int>
{
    { "A", 1 },
    { "B", 2 },
    { "C", 3 },
    { "D", 4 },
    { "E", 5 },
    { "F", 6 },
    { "G", 7 },
    { "H", 8 },
    { "I", 9 },
    { "J", 10 },
    { "K", 20 }
};
```

To get all 3 letter combos whose values add up to 23, first you need to get all 3 letter combos. So let's do that. The following function iterates through the dictionary and gets all 3 letter combos.

```
private static List<List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>> GetAll3LetterCombos(Dictionary<string, int> values)
{
    var comboList = new List<List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>>();
    for (int outer = 0; outer < values.Count; outer++)
    {
        for (int mid = outer + 1; mid < values.Count; mid++)
        {
            for (int inner = mid + 1; inner < values.Count; inner++)
            {
                var combo = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>
                {
                    values.ElementAt(outer),
                    values.ElementAt(mid),
                    values.ElementAt(inner)
                };
                comboList.Add(combo);
            }
        }
    }
    return comboList;
}
```

Then, using `LINQ`, we can filter out that result where the sum of values in each `KeyValuePair` is equal to 23.

```
var threeLetterCombos = GetAll3LetterCombos(values);
var addsTo23 = threeLetterCombos.Where(x => x.Sum(y => y.Value) == 23).ToList();
```

The result:

> [A 1] [B 2] [K 20]
>
> [D 4] [I 9] [J 10]
>
> [E 5] [H 8] [J 10]
>
> [F 6] [G 7] [J 10]
>
> [F 6] [H 8] [I 9]